# Elm: How to decode data from JSON API

Tags: json, elm

I have this data using http://jsonapi.org/ format:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "prospect",
            "id": "1",
            "attributes": {
                "provider_user_id": "1",
                "provider": "facebook",
                "name": "Julia",
                "invitation_id": 25
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "prospect",
            "id": "2",
            "attributes": {
                "provider_user_id": "2",
                "provider": "facebook",
                "name": "Sam",
                "invitation_id": 23
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have my models like:

```
type alias Model = {
  id: Int,
  invitation: Int,
  name: String,
  provider: String,
  provider_user_id: Int
 }

 type alias Collection = List Model
```

I want to decode the json into a Collection, but don't know how.

```
fetchAll: Effects Actions.Action
fetchAll =
  Http.get decoder (Http.url prospectsUrl [])
   |> Task.toResult
   |> Task.map Actions.FetchSuccess
   |> Effects.task

decoder: Json.Decode.Decoder Collection
decoder =
  ?
```

How do I implement decoder? Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

N.B. [Json.Decode docs](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Json-Decode)

Try this:

```
import Json.Decode as Decode exposing (Decoder)
import String

-- <SNIP>

stringToInt : Decoder String -> Decoder Int
stringToInt d =
  Decode.customDecoder d String.toInt

decoder : Decoder Model
decoder =
  Decode.map5 Model
    (Decode.field "id" Decode.string |> stringToInt )
    (Decode.at ["attributes", "invitation_id"] Decode.int)
    (Decode.at ["attributes", "name"] Decode.string)
    (Decode.at ["attributes", "provider"] Decode.string)
    (Decode.at ["attributes", "provider_user_id"] Decode.string |> stringToInt)

decoderColl : Decoder Collection
decoderColl =
  Decode.map identity
    (Decode.field "data" (Decode.list decoder))
```

The tricky part is using `stringToInt` to turn string fields into integers. I've followed the API example in terms of what is an int and what is a string. We luck out a little that `String.toInt` returns a `Result` as expected by `customDecoder` but there's enough flexibility that you can get a little more sophisticated and accept both. Normally you'd use `map` for this sort of thing; `customDecoder` is essentially `map` for functions that can fail.

The other trick was to use `Decode.at` to get inside the `attributes` child object.

Comment: I could be useful if you also explained how to map a value into a Result.

Comment: OP only asked about implementing the Decoder. To get the Result, call `Json.Decode.decodeString` or `decodeValue`.

Comment: And `:=` is now `Decode.field`. I've updated the example.

Comment: The last step should now be `decoderColl = Decode.map identity (Decode.field "data" (Decode.list decoder))`.