# Gson: Convert json string formatted with jsonapi.org ID based format to a java POJO

Tags: java, json, kotlin, gson, json-api

There is an example of how JSON responses should be formatted [here at jsonapi.org](http://jsonapi.org/). I want to use this convention but I need to check if this data can be serialized easily by Gson. Searching the web didn't come to any related solution. [This Q from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575003/) Is the most related but the language is neither Java nor Kotlin.
The main problem is that this convention says you should place your attributes like this:

```
"attributes": {
      "title": "JSON API paints my bikeshed!"
      "city": "Paris"
      ...
    },
```

But I do not know how to tell Gson to fetch attribute names and their corresponding content in this format. I do not want to make a collection of nested classes to represent that whole json string field by field.